# Ariflow can't seem to use Jinja templating correctly

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I have been working on an upgrade from Airflow 1.10.5 to 1.10.10 and one thing that has become a problem is templating a few things in some operators. Any task that involves rendering some sort of string with jinja has been problematic.

I have an operator which calls a python callable script:

```
def custom_s3_function(**kwargs):
    task = kwargs['task']   
    
    if cadence == '@hourly':
        ds = f'{{{{ ts }}}}'
    elif cadence =='@daily':
        ds = f'{{{{ ds }}}}'
    else:
        ds = f'{{{{ execution_date - macros.timedelta(seconds={600} + 1) }}}}'
    dsTemp = task.render_template('', ds, kwargs)  
 .......# etc
```

at this point when I run the dag, this task specifically gives me an error on the most recent line above (`dsTemp = task.render_template('', ds, kwargs)`):

```
ERROR - 'dict' object has no attribute 'from_string'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/custom_package/airflow/custom_file.py", line 125, in custom_s3_function
    dsTemp = task.render_template('', ds, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 752, in render_template
    return jinja_env.from_string(content).render(**context)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'from_string'
```

I have a variety of operators which have this same issue. Whenever I have to render using something like `dsTemp = task.render_template('', ds, kwargs)`, it throws this error. It never happened before upgrading. Obviously there were a lot of code changes that I can't go through here completely, but I'm struggling to narrow it down. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

```
dsTemp = task.render_template('', ds, kwargs)
```

should actually be

```
dsTemp = task.render_template(ds, kwargs)
```

(remove empty single quotes).

I guess `render_template` changed somewhere along the way.